# increase value count of array

Tags: java, arrays, mapping

I have an array containing a bunch of int's.

```
int[] screen_ids = {17, 17, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};
```

now i want to increase the value count of this array by a value lets say `1.4` after this action the array wil look like this:

```
int[] screen_ids = {17, 17, 17, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1};
```

how would i go about doing this. i tried the following, but i got stuck on the logic and the code doesn't work. tips and suggestions are very welcome! see my try below:

```
int[] more_data(int[] vals){
  ArrayList<Integer> updated_data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int count = 17; 
  for(int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
    if(vals[i] == count){
      temp.add(vals[i]);
    }else{
      temp.size() * 1.4; 
      for(int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++){
         updated_data.add(temp.get(j)); 
      }
    }
  }
  return updated_data;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you mean by increasing the value by `1.4`? How exactly are those values changing?

Comment: what i mean by 1.4 is that i want to increase the count for all unique values by 1.4. so if the array contains 2x 17 the new array should contain 3x 17 and so for all unique values. hope this makes it more clear!

Comment: i case i would get like 2.2 i would just increase it to 3 because that suits my needs better

Comment: I still don't really understand. Also note that we don't get notifications about your replies unless you @mention us.

Comment: i didnt know that @KevinWorkman , i will try to be more clear. lets say an array contains two indentical values lets say these values are 17. in a new array i want to copy the old values but increase the count of these values by 1.5 so the new array wil contain three values of 17. instead of the old array with two values of 17.

Comment: Let say you want to increase the count by 1.1 and there are 2 identical values 17. How many values of 17 a new array should contain ? 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @krokodilko it should contain 3 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i may have solved this problem. I had to put the array into an arraylist. i hope that is ok. but i have made it work i think tell me what you think..

```
public static void processData(int[] vals, int lookingFor, double incSize, List list) {
    double count = 0;
    for (int i : vals) {
        if (i == lookingFor) {
            System.out.println(i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("count: " + count);
    incSize = count * incSize;
    System.out.println("incBy: " + incSize);
    int rounded = (int) Math.round(incSize);
    System.out.println("rounded: " + rounded);
    for (int i = 0; i < rounded; i++) {
        list.add(lookingFor);
    }
    System.out.println("Result: ");
    for (Object i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] screen_ids = {17, 17, 13, 13, 13,
        12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9,
        9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};

    for (int i : screen_ids) {
        x.add(i);
    }
    processData(screen_ids, 17, 1.4, x);
    System.out.println(" x length: " + x.size());
}
```

Output:

```
17 17 count: 2.0 incBy: 2.8 rounded: 3 Result: 17 17 13 13 13 12 11 11 11 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 8 7 7 7 5 5 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 17 17 17  x length: 33
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unneccessary to have a method of the class, so I would make `moreData` `static` (and I would rename it to follow Java conventions); and I would pass in the `scale`-ing factor. Next, you might use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` (use a `LinkedHashMap` if you want a consistent order) to get the initial count of elements. Then you could use a `flatMapToInt` to generate an `IntStream` of the appropriate elements and counts with something like

```
static int[] moreData(int[] vals, double scale) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    IntStream.of(vals).forEachOrdered(i -> countMap.put(i, 
            1 + countMap.getOrDefault(i, 0)));
    return countMap.entrySet().stream().flatMapToInt(entry -> 
        IntStream.generate(() -> entry.getKey()).limit(
                Math.round(entry.getValue() * scale))).toArray();
}
```

Which I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 17, 17, 18, 18, 18 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moreData(arr, 1.5)));
}
```

Getting

```
[17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]
```

Comment: Do you know by any chance what java libraries is should import in processing? the code cant compile now.. thanks for the answer @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score -1):

Hope this one will help you

```
public class test {

    private static final List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(17, 17, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1);
    private static final List<Integer> newIds = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int lastChecked = 0;
        for (int id : ids) 
        {
            newIds.add(id);
            if (lastChecked != id)
                checkForIncrease(id);
            lastChecked = id;
        }

        ids.forEach(num -> System.out.print(num + " "));
        System.out.println();
        newIds.forEach(num -> System.out.print(num + " "));

    }

    private static void checkForIncrease(int val) 
    {
        final double mult = 1.4;

        int found = 0;

        for (int num : ids)
            if (num == val)
                found++;

        final double multResult = found * mult;
        if (multResult - found > 0.5 && found > 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < multResult - found; i++)
                newIds.add(val);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
17 17 13 13 13 12 11 11 11 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 8 7 7 7 5 5 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 
17 17 17 13 13 13 13 13 12 12 11 11 11 11 11 10 10 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used LinkedHashMap to store the count of each integer and then formed a ArrayList of the increased count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] screen_ids = {17, 17, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};
    System.out.println(screen_ids.length);
    int initial=1;

    LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> lhm=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<screen_ids.length;i++)
    {
        if(!lhm.containsKey(screen_ids[i]))
        {
            lhm.put(screen_ids[i], initial);
        }

        else
        {
            lhm.put(screen_ids[i],lhm.get(screen_ids[i])+1);
        }
    }

    List<Integer> screen_ids1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(Map.Entry m:lhm.entrySet()){  
          int new_count=(int)(((int)m.getValue())*1.4+1);
          lhm.put((int)m.getKey(), new_count);
          System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());

          for(int i=0;i<(int)m.getValue();i++)
          {
              screen_ids1.add((int)m.getKey());
          }
    }

    System.out.println(screen_ids1);
```